# FabricJS: Why cant I click on objects during animations?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I need a circle, which gets bigger every second. If I click the circle, it should disappear.

Ok so I added an animation and a mousedown function. But at the end of the animation the mousedown function does not work.

The circle is not recognized any more and is null until the animation finishes.

Any suggestions?

MyCode:

```
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var temp = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        fill: 'red',
        radius: 20
    });

temp.on('mousedown', function(e){
        console.log("clicked");
});

temp.selectable = false;

canvas.add(temp);

function animate(c){
    c.animate('radius', '80',{
        duration: 6000,
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
    });

}

animate(temp);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/euL7to2w/ live example

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [object#setCoords](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setCoords). in onChange handler.

***DEMO***

```js
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var temp = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  fill: 'red',
  radius: 20,
  selectable: false
});

temp.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  console.log("clicked");
  canvas.remove(temp);
  temp.isRemoved = true;
});

canvas.add(temp);

function animate(c) {
  c.animate('radius', '80', {
    duration: 6000,
    onChange: function() {
      c.setCoords();
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
    },
    abort: function() {
      return c.isRemoved;
    }
  });

}

animate(temp);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width=300 height=200></canvas>
<div id='result'></div>
<div id='result2'>

</div>
```